# Returning data to Django form for editing

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am using multiple forms which opens in modals from the same page at my Django app. I got it to work with custom functions, but now I'm a bit struggling on how to add editing functionality since I am very new to Django.

Since this way working with forms is very new to me I got lost where should I provide instance that form would show already entered data for that instance.

This is form variable in views.py

```
edit_employment_form = _get_form(request, EditEmploymentForm, "edit_employment_form_pre")
```

This is function I use to differiante between forms. (Or at least i think that this does it)

```
def _get_form(request, formcls, prefix):
        data = request.POST if prefix in request.POST else None
        return formcls(data, prefix=prefix)
```

This is my full view in views.py to better understand structure. Below request.method condition is variable employment_id which I am going to use to filter instance. I get that id from button in html which itself is form and returns me item id from for loop.

```
@login_required
def person_profile(request, person_id):
    current_user = request.user
    user = Person.objects.get(user=current_user)
    people = Person.objects.all()
    jobs = Job.objects.all()
    person = Person.objects.get(pk=person_id)
    employments = Employments.objects.filter(person_id=person_id).order_by("-start_date")
    workflows = Workflows.objects.filter(person_id=person_id).order_by("-workflow_date")
    sources = Sources.objects.filter(person_id=person_id).order_by("-source_date")
    tags = Tags.objects.filter(person_id=person_id)
    comments = Comments.objects.filter(person_id=person_id)
    person_calls = ScheduledCalls.objects.filter(person_id=person_id).order_by("-date")
    scheduled_calls = ScheduledCalls.objects.filter(user_id=user.id).order_by("-date")
    reminders = Reminders.objects.filter(person_id=person_id)
    notes = Notes.objects.filter(user_id=person_id)
    gdpr = GDPR.objects.filter(person_id=person_id).order_by("-is_valid")
    valid_gdpr_filter = GDPR.objects.filter(person_id=person_id, is_valid="Valid")
    license_b_filter = Licenses.objects.filter(person_id=person_id, license="B")
    license_c_filter = Licenses.objects.filter(person_id=person_id, license="C")
    license_ce_filter = Licenses.objects.filter(person_id=person_id, license="CE")
    license_95_filter = Licenses.objects.filter(person_id=person_id, license="95")
    skill_fd_filter = Skills.objects.filter(person_id=person_id, skill="FD experience")
    skill_op_filter = Skills.objects.filter(person_id=person_id, skill="OP experience")
    skill_ce_filter = Skills.objects.filter(person_id=person_id, skill="CE driver experience")
    skill_tl_filter = Skills.objects.filter(person_id=person_id, skill="Team Leading experience")


    if valid_gdpr_filter:
        valid_gdpr = GDPR.objects.get(person_id=person_id, is_valid="Valid")
        end_date_calc = ((valid_gdpr.consent_date + timedelta(days=1095)) - date.today())
        days = int(str(end_date_calc).split(" ", 1)[0])

        if days > 30:
            consent_ends_in = "more than a month"
        elif days > 14:
            consent_ends_in = "around 2 weeks"
        elif days < 14:
            consent_ends_in = "less than 2 weeks!"        
    else:
        valid_gdpr = None
        consent_ends_in = None

    if license_b_filter: 
        license_b = Licenses.objects.get(person_id=person_id, license="B")
    else:
        license_b = None

    if license_c_filter: 
        license_c = Licenses.objects.get(person_id=person_id, license="C")
    else:
        license_c = None  

    if license_ce_filter: 
        license_ce = Licenses.objects.get(person_id=person_id, license="CE")
    else:
        license_ce = None  

    if license_95_filter: 
        license_95 = Licenses.objects.get(person_id=person_id, license="95")
    else:
        license_95 = None                  

    if skill_fd_filter: 
        skill_fd = Skills.objects.get(person_id=person_id, skill="FD experience")
    else:
        skill_fd = None

    if skill_op_filter: 
        skill_op = Skills.objects.get(person_id=person_id, skill="OP experience")
    else:
        skill_op = None

    if skill_ce_filter: 
        skill_ce = Skills.objects.get(person_id=person_id, skill="CE driver experience")
    else:
        skill_ce = None

    if skill_tl_filter: 
        skill_tl = Skills.objects.get(person_id=person_id, skill="Team Leading experience")
    else:
        skill_tl = None            


    if request.method == "POST":
        new_employment_form = _get_form(request, EmploymentForm, "new_employment_form_pre")
        new_application_form = _get_form(request, ApplicationForm, "new_application_form_pre")
        new_consent_form = _get_form(request, GDPRForm, "new_consent_form_pre")
        edit_employment_form = _get_form(request, EditEmploymentForm, "edit_employment_form_pre")
        employment_id = request.POST.get("employment_id")
        print(employment_id)    

        if new_employment_form.is_bound and new_employment_form.is_valid():
            new_employment_form.instance.person_id = person
            new_employment_form.instance.hired_by = user
            new_employment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_employment_form.save()
            person.person_type = "Current Employee"
            person.save()
            candidate_gdpr = GDPR.objects.get(person_id=person_id, is_valid="Valid")
            candidate_gdpr.is_valid = "Invalid"
            candidate_gdpr.save()
            return redirect("person_profile", person_id)
        
        if new_application_form.is_bound and new_application_form.is_valid():
            new_application_form.instance.person_id = person
            new_application_form.save(commit=False)
            new_application_form.save()
            workflow = Workflows()
            workflow.workflow_date = date.today()
            workflow.stage = "New Applicant"
            workflow.person_id = Person.objects.get(id=person_id)
            workflow.save()
            return redirect("person_profile", person_id)
        
        if new_consent_form.is_bound and new_consent_form.is_valid():
            file = request.POST.get("consent_file")
            input_date = request.POST.get("consent_date")
            consent_date = datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            new_consent_form.instance.consent_file = file
            new_consent_form.instance.person_id = person
            new_consent_form.instance.consent_date = consent_date
            new_consent_form.instance.consent_end_date = consent_date + timedelta(days=1095)
            new_consent_form.save(commit=False)
            new_consent_form.save()
            return redirect("person_profile", person_id)
        
        if edit_employment_form.is_bound and edit_employment_form.is_valid():
            return redirect("person_profile", person_id)

        

        
    return render(request, "person/person_profile.html", {"person" : person,
                                                          "people" : people,
                                                          "jobs" : jobs, 
                                                          "employments" : employments,
                                                          "workflows" : workflows,
                                                          "sources" : sources,
                                                          "tags" : tags,
                                                          "comments" : comments,
                                                          "scheduled_calls" : scheduled_calls,
                                                          "reminders" : reminders,
                                                          "notes" : notes,
                                                          "gdpr" : gdpr,
                                                          "valid_gdpr" : valid_gdpr,
                                                          "consent_ends_in": consent_ends_in,
                                                          "license_b" : license_b,
                                                          "license_c" : license_c,
                                                          "license_ce" : license_ce,
                                                          "license_95" : license_95,
                                                          "skill_fd" : skill_fd,
                                                          "skill_op" : skill_op,
                                                          "skill_ce" : skill_ce,
                                                          "skill_tl" : skill_tl,
                                                          "person_calls" : person_calls,
                                                          "scheduled_calls" : scheduled_calls,
                                                          "new_employment_form" : EmploymentForm(prefix = "new_employment_form_pre"),
                                                          "new_application_form" : ApplicationForm(prefix = "new_application_form_pre"),
                                                          "new_consent_form" : GDPRForm(prefix="new_consent_form_pre"),
                                                          "edit_employment_form" : EditEmploymentForm(prefix="edit_employment_form_pre"),
                                                          })
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to pass [the instance of an object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) to edit the object. For example:

```
# method

def _get_form(request, formcls, prefix, instance=None):
    data = request.POST if prefix in request.POST else None
    return formcls(data, prefix=prefix, instance=instance)

# usage
def edit_employee(request, employee_id)
    employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=employee_id)
    if request.method == "GET":
       form = _get_form(request, EditEmploymentForm, "edit_employment_form_pre", employee)
    # rest of the code

# url
path('employee/edit/<int:employee_id>', edit_employee),
```